# images are not loading python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

hello i coded this simple game when it normal it working but when i make it inside a function to make other screens but player and enemy images are not loading and i don't know why so i searched every web and i could not find an answer and i think finding answer from a coder is better so please help me
here is my code

```
import pygame, sys
import math
from pygame import mixer
import random

# initialize the pygame
pygame.init()


# the screen                      #width height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 800))  # Y and X

# Background
background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")

# Background sound
mixer.music.load("background.wav")
mixer.music.play(-1)

# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space invadars")
icon = pygame.image.load("icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load("player.png")
playerX = 500
playerY = 700
playerX_change = 0

# Ememy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 1

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load("enemy.png"))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 1016))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(10, 100))
    enemyX_change.append(0.7)
    enemyY_change.append(40)

# Bullet
bulletImg = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 700
bulletX_change = 0.8
bulletY_change = 3
bullet_state = "ready"

# kills
kills_value = 0
kills_value_font = pygame.font.Font("Alien.ttf", 32)

textX = 10
textY = 10

# Game Over text
game_over_font = pygame.font.Font("Alien.ttf", 72)



def show_kills(x, y):
    kills = kills_value_font.render("Aliens Killed :" + " " + str(kills_value), True, (25, 184, 255))
    screen.blit(kills, (x, y))


def game_over_text():
    game_over_text = game_over_font.render("GAME OVER ", True, (25, 184, 255))
    screen.blit(game_over_text, (350, 400))

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def space_invadors():
    global playerX,playerY,playerX_change,bulletY,bulletX,bullet_state,kills_value,enemyY,enemyX,enemyX_change,playerImg
    while True:
        # screen
        screen.fill((29, 41, 81))
        # Background image
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        screen.blit(playerImg,(0,0))
        screen.blit(bulletImg, (0,0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()


            # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    playerX_change = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_change = +1
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if bullet_state == "ready":
                        bullet_sound = mixer.Sound("laser.ogg")
                        bullet_sound.play()
                        bulletX = playerX
                        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_change = 0

        # keeping the player inside the game cords
        playerX += playerX_change

        if playerX <= 0:
            playerX = 1016
        elif playerX >= 1016:
            playerX = 0
        # Bullet movement
        if bulletY <= 0:
            bulletY = 700
            bullet_state = "ready"
        if bullet_state == "fire":
            fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
            bulletY -= bulletY_change
            # keeping the player inside the game cords

            playerX += playerX_change

            if playerX <= 0:
                playerX = 1016
            elif playerX >= 1016:
                playerX = 0
            # Bullet movement
            if bulletY <= 0:
                bulletY = 700
                bullet_state = "ready"
            if bullet_state == "fire":
                fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
                bulletY -= bulletY_change

            # enemy movement

            for i in range(num_of_enemies):

                # Game Over
                if enemyY[i] > 645:
                    for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                        enemyY[j] = 2000
                    game_over_text()
                    break


                enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
                if enemyX[i] <= 0:
                    enemyX_change[i] = 0.7
                    enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
                elif enemyX[i] >= 1016:
                    enemyX_change[i] = -0.7
                    enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
                # collision
                collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
                if collision:
                    dieing_sounds = mixer.Sound("gotcha-bitch.mp3")
                    dieing_sounds.play()
                    bulletY = 700
                    bullet_state = "ready"
                    kills_value += 1
                    enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 1016)
                    enemyY[i] = random.randint(10, 100)
                enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)



        (playerX, playerY)
        show_kills(textX, textY)
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.update()
space_invadors()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the images in the functions. For example. Change this:

```
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))
```

to this:

```
def player(x, y, playerImg):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))
```

Or maybe better:

```
def blit_img(x, y, img):
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))

blit_img(10, 20, playerImg)
blit_img(30, 20, enemyImg[0])
blit_img(60, 20, enemyImg[1])
```